# Finding the closest smaller value in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object

```
let data = [{ id: 1, time_in: 2 }, { id: 4, time_in: 10 }, { id: 4, time_in: 6 }, { id: 9, time_in: 18 }, { id: 4, time_in: 14 }]
```

I want to find which element of this array has time_in closest to a given number, say 17. So in this case the result should be { id: 4, time_in: 14 } and not { id: 9, time_in: 18 }. I tried to reduce function but it gives the closest value and not the closest smaller value.

Here's what I have already tried

```
  let data = [{ id: 1, time_in: 2 }, { id: 4, time_in: 10 }, { id: 4, time_in: 6 }, { id: 9, time_in: 18 }, { id: 4, time_in: 14 }],
            pivot = 17,
                result = data.reduce((a, b) =>  Math.abs(a.time_in - pivot) < Math.abs(b.time_in - pivot)
            ? a
            : b
        );



        console.log(result);
```

Comment: Do you need the matching *object*, or only the matching *number*?

Comment: matching object

Comment: cant you use simple forEach method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce` works, but don't use `Math.abs`. Check if the current item being iterated over has a `time_in` value which is less than the pivot *and* is greater than the `time_in` value of the accumulator (which is the best matching object found so far):

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    time_in: 2
  }, {
    id: 4,
    time_in: 10
  }, {
    id: 4,
    time_in: 6
  }, {
    id: 4,
    time_in: 18
  }, {
    id: 4,
    time_in: 14
  }],
  pivot = 17,
  result = data.reduce((a, b) => (
    b.time_in < pivot && b.time_in > a.time_in
      ? b
      : a
  ), { time_in: -Infinity });


console.log(result);
```